# Question about continuous onto maps of homeomorphic spaces.

Tags: general-topology, functions

If $f:(A,T) \rightarrow (B,T_1)$ is continuous and onto, and $$(A,T) \cong (C,T_2) \land (B,T_1) \cong (D, T_3)$$ $$\Rightarrow \exists g: (C,T_2) \rightarrow (D,T_3)$$ that is continuous and onto.

Comment: I suppose you mean $(D,T_3)$ in the first line instead of $(D,T_2)$

Comment: Whoops, fixed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the indicated homeomorphisms are $h_A$ and $h_D$, just take
$$g = h_B\circ f\circ h_A^{-1}$$
It's continuous and onto because each of the elements of the composition are.

Comment: So because:
$h^{-1}_A : C \rightarrow A, f: A \rightarrow B \text{ and } h_B : B \rightarrow D$ , their composition yields the desired result and is continuous and onto since the composition of continuous and onto elements is a continuous and onto function?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You may or may not need to prove the simple lemmas on which this relies (composition of continuous functions is continuous, composition of onto functions is onto).